# Domain of Indefinite Integral - Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What's the domain of this function?

$F(x) = -\int _0^x\:\frac{\ln\left(1-t\right)}{t}dt$

In the 'Answers' Section it says $(-\infty,1)$ but I think it is $(-\infty,1]$ since $\frac{\ln\left(1-t\right)}{t}$ is defined and continuous in $\left(-\infty \:,\:0\right)\cup \left(0,\:1 \:\right)$ and continuous by extension in $x=0$ and $x=1$.

I don't know why I should treat $1$ differently from $0$, thank you for your time.
**Edit:** I miss calculated $\lim _{t\to 1}\:\frac{log\left(1-t\right)}{t}$ and it happens to be divergent. Now I'm trying to show that $F$ is continuous by extension in $x=1$ (to the left) but I don't even know how that since the limit happens to be divergent.

Comment: How do you extend $\ln(1-x)/x$ to $x=1$?

Comment: In fact, $-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-t)}{t}dt =\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. So you are right.

Comment: @Song I don't think there would be an error on this worksheets. The next question is 'Show that F can be extended by continuity to the left of $x = 1$' which implies that x = 1 doesn't belong to the function's domain. I'm translating it, if someone doesn't understand just tell me.

Comment: I think it is a matter of definition. If $-\int_0^x \frac{\ln(1-t)}{t}dt$ is defined as proper Riemann integral, then $x=1$ does not belong to the domain of $F$. (But if we allow improper Riemann integral, then $x=1$ belongs to the domain.)

Comment: @EclipseSun Wait, you're right. It is divergent at $1$. Then how can F be extended by continuity in $x=1$(left)?

Comment: You can't extend the *integrand* by continuity at $x=1.$ As you say, it diverges there (unlike the case at $x=0$ where the limit is finite so the integrand can be extended). However, the divergence is only logarithmic, and hence $\lim_{b\to 1^-}\int_0^b \frac{\ln(1-x}{x}dx$ is finite. So $F(x)$ *can* be extended by continuity. (Another way of expressing this is that the improper Riemann integral exists).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen With what I've learned, I wouldn't come up with the fact that the limit is finite because the divergence is logarithmic. Is there another way to show that the improper Riemann integral exists?

Comment: @MárioBelga Atmos's answer below suggests you use the fact that it's dominated by a $1/\sqrt{x}$ divergence. Alternatively there is the fact that $\int \ln(x)dx = x\ln(x)-x + C$ which is enough to show that a pure logarithmic divergence has finite integral.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is for the point $1$ you have letting $x=1-h$
$$
\frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{x}=\frac{\ln\left(h\right)}{1-h}\underset{(0)}{\sim}\ln\left(h\right)
$$

And $\displaystyle \left|\ln\left(h\right)\right|\underset{(0)}{=}o\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}\right)$ and you know that $h \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{h}}$ is integrable on $\left]0,1/2\right]$.
With equivalence criteria, $\displaystyle x \mapsto \frac{\ln\left(1-x\right)}{x}$ is integrable on $\left[1/2,1\right[$.

It is not because the integrand diverges that the integral does not exist, for example 
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\ln\left(x\right)\text{d}x=-1
$$
while $\ln\left(x\right) \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}-\infty$
This, just because
$$
\int_{x}^{1}\ln\left(t\right)\text{d}t \underset{x \rightarrow 0}{\rightarrow}-1
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\displaystyle \int \ln(t) dt = x \ln(x) - x$, then we can calculate integrale of $\ln(x)$ in local $0^+$

$\dfrac{\ln(1-t)}{t} \sim \ln(1-t)$ in local $1^-$

Then $F(x=1)$ is **defined**.